# Onclick event with an argument = Not implemented?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Hoping for some advice here, I'm quite new to javascript and coding in general so I'm sure there are better ways to do what I need, however any help much appreciated ....

I have a piece of javascript that creates a table, the amount of rows being dynamic.
When I call the javascript I'm passing a few bits of info over, and one of these is an array. The array contains in each element a long string of text.

So I create the table with X rows showing some identifying data. I also create a radio button for each row with an on click event. The idea being that when the user clicks on the radio button, then the long string from the array element will be displayed in a separate text box.

I have managed to get to the point that the table is created and that when the radio button is selected the onclick event fires and loads a piece of data into the txt box. However that piece of data is hardcoded (txtbox.value=array[1])
What I'm now trying to do is load the relevant string from the array, depending on what radio button is clicked.
If i change my onclick event to onclick=function(ID) and my function to function(ID) I'm getting an error 'Not implented'

It appears to be generated from the onclick event rather than the function ...
The following works :

```
R1.onclick=clicktest;

function clicktest()
{
txtbox.value=array[1]
}
```

The following generates the error

```
R1.onclick=clicktest(1);

function clicktest(id)
{
txtbox.value=array[id]
}
```

Apologies if this isn't so clear.

Answer (score 2):

Using this code

```
R1.onclick=clicktest(1);
```

You're executing `clicktest(1)` and assigning the result as event handler.

You could change it by this in to make it work

```
R1.onclick = function() { clicktest(1) };
```

Comment: Brilliant that works !!!
Could I be cheeky and ask you how the above works, I've not seen it before ?

Comment: @user2436469: I'm assigning `R1.onclick` to an inline function declaration. A function can be assigned to a variable like any other type (it doesn't difer to `var a = 4;`)